bootstrapTable Load function not generating checkbox
I have created a html table using the following code:
<table id="vendor-table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-class="table-active" data-sortable="true"
        data-search="true",data-virtual-scroll="false">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-field="brand" data-sortable="true">Brand </th>
            <th data-field="client" data-sortable="true">Client</th>
            <th data-field="spid" data-sortable="true">Selling Partner ID</th>
            <th data-field="acct" data-sortable="true">Account Type</th>
            <th data-field="cc" data-sortable="true">Country Code</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody></tbody>
</table>

I have created a function to populate the table. Below is the function:
function updateVendorTable(filteredVendorAccts) {
    var table = $('#vendor-table');

    // Map the data to include the checkbox column before the id column
    var mappedData = filteredVendorAccts.map(function (account) {
        return {
            '':'<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="vendor-ids" value="' + account.id + '" /></label>',
            brand: account.brand,
            client: account.client,
            spid: account.sp_id,
            acct: account.account_type,
            cc: account.country_code

        };
    });

    // Update the table data using the load method
    table.bootstrapTable('load', mappedData);
   
}

I expect the html to contain the checkbox for the first value returned by the function i.e '':'', but the checkbox column is populated with -. Below is the screenshot:


I have made sure that the value is returned for '' column. Below is an example:
{
    "": "<label class=\"checkbox\"><input type=\"checkbox\" name=\"vendor-ids\" value=\"15324\" /></label>",
    "brand": "Edge",
    "client": "GSK_DE",
    "spid": "amzn1.vg.5666682",
    "acct": "vendor",
    "cc": "DE",
    "id": 15324
}

Am I missing something? Below is the expected output:

Any help would be highly appreciated.

Document Ready: Ensure that the code runs after the document is fully loaded using $(document).ready().


$(document).ready(function () {
        let data = [
          {
            "": '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="vendor-ids" value="15324" /></label>',
            brand: "Edge",
            client: "GSK_DE",
            spid: "amzn1.vg.5666682",
            acct: "vendor",
            cc: "DE",`enter code here`
            id: 15324,
          },
        ];
        // Initialize table with data
        updateVendorTable(data);
      });
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.21.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.7.1/jquery.min.js"></script>





<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <link href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.21.1/bootstrap-table.min.css" rel="stylesheet" />
    <title>Bootstrap Table Example</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container mt-5">
      <table id="vendor-table" data-toggle="table" data-sort-class="table-active" data-sortable="true" data-search="true" ,data-virtual-scroll="false">
        <thead>
          <tr>
            <th></th>
            <th data-field="brand" data-sortable="true">Brand</th>
            <th data-field="client" data-sortable="true">Client</th>
            <th data-field="spid" data-sortable="true">Selling Partner ID</th>
            <th data-field="acct" data-sortable="true">Account Type</th>
            <th data-field="cc" data-sortable="true">Country Code</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody></tbody>
      </table>
    </div>

    <script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.3.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/bootstrap-table/1.21.1/bootstrap-table.min.js"></script>

    <script>
      $(document).ready(function () {
        let data = [
          {
            "": '<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="vendor-ids" value="15324" /></label>',
            brand: "Edge",
            client: "GSK_DE",
            spid: "amzn1.vg.5666682",
            acct: "vendor",
            cc: "DE",
            id: 15324,
          },
        ];
        // Initialize table with data
        updateVendorTable(data);
      });

      function updateVendorTable(filteredVendorAccts) {
        var table = $("#vendor-table");

        // Map the data to include the checkbox column before the id column
        var mappedData = filteredVendorAccts.map(function (account) {
          return {
            "": `<label class="checkbox"><input type="checkbox" name="vendor-ids" value="${account.id}" /></label>`,
            brand: account.brand,
            client: account.client,
            spid: account.spid,
            acct: account.acct,
            cc: account.cc,
          };
        });

        table.bootstrapTable("load", mappedData);
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>




It is still giving -. Please run the code snippet
